# ASP MVC4 Razor [Authorize] tag with own DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i have created a ASP MVC 4 RAZOR Web-Application an i have created my own Database where i store Username and Password. And i use FormAuthentification i have set a Cookie with the Username.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acc.Username, false);
```

When i use my own DB the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] Tag did not work. Is it possible that i can use this tag's with my DB ? Or how can i say that the loggedin User X has only access to Controller A Action B ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Membership Provider. Here is great article about it http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx